# inverse list secondary key index implementation?

Tags: c#, inverted-index

I have searched about the implementation of the inverse list secondary key index but have not found any result in any language especially c#.
if anyone can help me in its implementation?

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the implementation of the inverted list secondary key index in c#.i want it In a research for it and did not find an answer

Answer (score 0):

Be nice if you gave some class and/or property names but this is what i have

```
var listReversed = myList.OrderByDescending(x => x.SecondIndex).ToList();
```